# Php not accessing the Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

**i have a form file with name form1.php**

```
<?PHP
//form.php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
        <title>form</title>
</head>

<body>
        <?PHP if (isset ($_SESSION["notfound"])) { ?> 
                <h2 style="text-align:center">Wrong user name or password</h2>
        <?PHP unset($_SESSION["notfound"]);}
         if (isset ($_SESSION["empty"])) {?>
                <h2 style="text-align:center">Empty</h2>
        <?PHP unset($_SESSION["empty"]); }?>

    <form name="signin" action="http://localhost/M1.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <label>
            Username<input type="text" name="name" size="32"/>
            </label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <label>
            Password <input type="password" name="pass" size="32"/>
            </label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

**and controll file M1.php**

```
<?php
$name=$_POST["name"];
$pass=$_POST["pass"];
if((!empty($name)) && (!empty($pass)))
{
    session_start();
    if($conection=mysql_connect("localhost","","")===false)
        die("not connect to data base");

    if(mysql_select_db('login',$conection) ===false)
        die("data base not found");


    $sql =sprintf("SELECT `password` FROM `signin` WHERE `username`= '%s' ",mysql_real_escape_string($name));

    $dbpass=mysql_query($sql);

    if ($dbpass==$pass) 
    {
        $_SESSION["authenticated"]=true;
        header("Location: http://localhost/home.php");
        exit;
    }
     else   //if ($dbpass===false)
    {
        $_SESSION["notfound"]=true;
        header("Location: http://localhost/form1.php");
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    $_SESSION["empty"]=true;
    header("Location: http://localhost/form1.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

**i am useing xampp for runing them 
i have data base loging which contain a table signin 
when i fill the form with same user name and password which i save in signin table and click submit it return me on form1.php with session 'notfoun'
and when i submit empty form it return me without seting empty session  **

Comment: session_start(); should be at the very top of file

Comment: Your db access code is wrong. The result of a `$dbpass=mysql_query($sql);` is a resource handle and not the password from the query. You now need to fetch the results that your query generated. Have a look at the manual http://uk1.php.net/mysql_fetch_row

Comment: thanks due to this empty file is also responding empty but data base is stil not accessing

Comment: $dbpass=mysql_query($sql); is wrong yar..
Use mysql_fetch_row() or mysql_fetch_array()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's firstly good time to make use of `PDO` or `mysqli` rather then using `mysql` which is deprecated in latest PHP version.

While passing db connection values, I feel you missed out the username & password, which should help you connect the database.

Later, `mysql_query("SELECT_QUERY");` returns result object, whose values should be read by `mysql_fetch_assoc()` which returns the db row into associative array form.

Finally your code should look like,

```
$sql =sprintf("SELECT `password` FROM `signin` WHERE `username`= '%s' ",mysql_real_escape_string($name));

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$dbpass = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$dbpass = $dbpass['password'];
if ($dbpass==$pass) 
{
    $_SESSION["authenticated"]=true;
    header("Location: http://localhost/home.php");
    exit;
}
 else   //if ($dbpass===false)
{
    $_SESSION["notfound"]=true;
    header("Location: http://localhost/form1.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: **i change my code but still it is not working and shows** _wrong username and password_

Comment: Hope the code worked for you, but also start reading on *mysqli* or PDO http://in1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Answer (score 1):

You are not fetching data from database and you make a condition based on execute query = $pass which will be always false, so change to

```
$dbpass=mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($dbpass);
$passw = $result['password'];

if ($passw==$pass) 
{
  //logged
```

As side note i would say a couple of thing. First I notice you sanitized your input which is a good pratice, but you really should switch to prepared statments with either [**`PDO`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**`mysqli`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) so you will avoid any risk of [**`mysql injection`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1), also because `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Second saving a password in plain text in database is a very bad pratice, you should really encrypt it and save an hash of the password in database, there is anice post about that [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords). Further more I think that `session_start();` should be placed at the top of your file to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you're getting?

Anyway, how do you connect through your database? I see you have put the username and password as an empty string. You should try to put in a user/pass of an existing user:

`mysql_connect` syntax:

```
mysql_connect(host,username,password,newlink,clientflag)
```

example:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
```

or

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","password")
```

Comment: Of course he's left them blank, or did you expect him to post his database login credentials on SO?

Comment: Lol of course not. But he didn't refer anything regarding the user and pass, so this could be a problem.

Comment: i am using xampp for phpMyAdmin & the deafult username and password is empty. I try it also on wampp where fill the deafult username and deafult password & and also make the suggested changes but it still not work